# What is the effect of adding a capacitor and a battery in parallel?

Tags: capacitor, batteries

I have a battery powered device (motion sensor) CR2032 or CR2477.

I have consulted the sample designs and found that there is usually a capacitor with a value from 220uF to 330uF in parallel with the battery.

What is the effect of this capacitor other than ripple voltage flattening? Is it related to the RC charging and discharging circuit?

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Look at this discharge curve from [this CR2032 data sheet](https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/cr2032.pdf): -

[image]

**The yellow circle and line and orange words are my addition.**

Under a load of 6.8 mA, the battery terminal voltage drops by about 0.2 volts. This means roughly that the output impedance of the battery is 0.2/0.0068 = 29 Ω.

So, if you wanted to take peaks of (say) 100 mA, the battery voltage cannot be sustained without dropping uselessly low. Hence, we put capacitors in parallel to act as temporary sources of energy that the battery cannot provide.

If the battery load took 100 mA pulses for a millisecond (now and then) and, we wanted the capacitor to not drop anything more than 0.3 volts (for example), we would need a capacitance of: -

$$C = I \times \dfrac{\text{time}}{\text{volt drop}} = 0.1 \times 0.001/0.3 = \text{333 uF}$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: This. Most coin cell batteries have a ridiculously high internal resistance. If you’ve ever opened one of those small key chain led lights they usually don’t even have a series resistor with the LED, they simply rely on the battery’s internal resistance to limit the LED current.

Comment: > rely on the battery's internal resistance

Wow, that's... something alright. 29 ohm internal resistance, 1.7V forward gives 44mA. That's an extreme example but that's not too healthy for a single 5mm LED

Comment: @BrydonGibson Look at the top of the picture, the internal resistance is given. It is much higher for a continuous current than for a pulse current (which was the basis for Andy's answer computations).

Comment: @Sacha no, that isn't the case. The battery internal resistance won't change that much under a heavier load. My computation is all about trickle charging a capacitor that handles the short duration load surges.

Comment: @Andyaka That might have been poorly formulated, but that's what I was mentioning.

Answer (score 13):

Another usage (other than Andy aka's answer) may be to support replacing the battery without causing a reset.
Maybe not in the motion detection application, but for an RTC, volatile memory or similar.

Many devices with button cell batteries specify that you can replace the battery without memory loss if it is done within 10 seconds or something similar. And of course, assuming it is done before the old battery is completely dead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply